# how to sum values from a python dictionary having key as tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary with key as tuple

```
D_grpTagReport = { ('Tag1', '1'):345.56 ,
                   ('Tag1', '2'):45.6 ,
                   ('Tag2', '3'):3.1 ,
                   ('Tag3', '1'):21.56 ,
                   ('Tag2', '3'):1.56 ,
                 }
```

I would like to get the sum of values for each unique Tag. Is there any built in utility that can be used to process this dictionary.

Result Example:

```
Tag1 : 391.16     # (total of all Tag1)
Tag2 : 4.66       # (total of all Tag2) 
Tag3 : 21.56      # (total of all Tag3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this , first take `.items()` for the dictionary and then sort this list based on the first element of the key and the use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on it with `key` as the first element of the key (first element of first element of the tuple of `key,value`). Then for each group you can take `sum()` over the values to get what you want. Example -

```
from itertools import groupby
for key,group in groupby(sorted(D_grpTagReport.items()),key=lambda x:x[0][0]):
    total = sum(g[1] for g in group)
    print(key,':',total)
```

Please note you result is a bit wrong, and so is your dictionary, since `dictionary` cannot have same key with multiple values.

Demo -

```
>>> D_grpTagReport = { ('Tag1', '1'):345.56 ,
...                    ('Tag1', '2'):45.6 ,
...                    ('Tag2', '3'):3.1 ,
...                    ('Tag3', '1'):21.56 ,
...                    ('Tag2', '3'):1.56 ,
...                  }
>>>
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for key,group in groupby(sorted(D_grpTagReport.items()),key=lambda x:x[0][0]):
...     total = sum(g[1] for g in group)
...     print(key,':',total)
...
Tag1 : 391.16
Tag2 : 1.56
Tag3 : 21.56
```

Comment: The dictionary is right as the key tuple is unique, each tuple item could be duplicate, however, as a whole key, its unique.

Comment: Not the keys in your question, you have `('Tag2', '3')` twice.

Comment: oops, sorry, you are right, I overlooked that. I checked with my code it worked great and does not have duplicate keys. Thanks for your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

Some good answers already, but here's a different (simpler IMO) approach.

```
d = {('A', '1'): 2, ('A', '2'): 5, ('B', '1'): 1}
keys={k[0]:0 for k in d.keys()}
for key in d:
    keys[key[0]] = keys[key[0]] + d[key]
print(keys)  # {'A': 7, 'B': 1}
```

Once more with the data from the OP:

```
d = { ('Tag1', '1'):345.56 ,
      ('Tag1', '2'):45.6 ,
      ('Tag2', '3'):3.1 ,
      ('Tag3', '1'):21.56 ,
      ('Tag2', '3'):1.56 ,
    }
keys={k[0]:0 for k in d.keys()}
for key in d:
    keys[key[0]] = keys[key[0]] + d[key]
print(keys)  # {'Tag1': 391.16, 'Tag2': 1.56, 'Tag3': 21.56}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is simple!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D_grpTagReport = { ('Tag1', '1'):345.56 ,
...                    ('Tag1', '2'):45.6 ,
...                    ('Tag2', '3'):3.1 ,
...                    ('Tag3', '1'):21.56 ,
...                    ('Tag2', '3'):1.56 ,
...                  }
>>> result = defaultdict(int)
>>> for t in D_grpTagReport:
...     result[t[0]] += D_grpTagReport[t]
...
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Tag3': 21.56, 'Tag1': 391.16, 'Tag2': 1.56})
```